# Illegal hour value '58' for java.sql.Time type in value

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

Tengo una duda con este problema al parecer al hacer el `select` y hacer la operacion con el metodo `TIMESTAMPDIFF` de *MySQL* me bota el siguiente error:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '58' for java.sql.Time type in value '58:13:01.
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimeFast(ResultSetRow.java:970)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getTimeFast(ByteArrayRow.java:223)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimeInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5926)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTime(ResultSetImpl.java:5662)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:4898)
>   at Gerencia_Proyectos.frmIndicadores.jButton1MouseClicked(frmIndicadores.java:116)
>   at Gerencia_Proyectos.frmIndicadores.access$000(frmIndicadores.java:23)
>   at Gerencia_Proyectos.frmIndicadores$1.mouseClicked(frmIndicadores.java:64)
>   at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
>   at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '58' for java.sql.Time type in value '58:13:01.
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.TimeUtil.fastTimeCreate(TimeUtil.java:1023)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.fastTimeCreate(ResultSetImpl.java:1012)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimeFast(ResultSetRow.java:964)
>   ... 39 more
> ```

He leido por alli y creo que es porque en java solo me permite operar hasta max 24 horas por eso es que me sale el error porque supera, son 58 horas. En cambio si pruebo mi query en el MySQL si funciona, pero en java no.

Les dejo el query:

```
select
  sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,r.fecha_envio_rq,a.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo demorado entre fecha de envio y autorizacion',
  sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,a.fecha_aprobacion,vba.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo demorado entre fecha de autorizacion y almacén',
  sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,vba.fecha_aprobacion,vbl.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo demorado entre fecha de almacén y logística',
  sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,vbl.fecha_aprobacion,vbo.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo demorado entre fecha de logística y obra',
  sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,r.fecha_envio_rq,vbo.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo total demorado'
from requerimiento r
join autorizacion a on r.cod_rq=a.cod_rq
join vb_almacen vba on r.cod_rq=vba.cod_rq
join vb_logistica vbl on r.cod_rq=vbl.cod_rq
join vb_obra vbo on r.cod_rq=vbo.cod_rq
where r.cod_rq = '2'
```

Y lo ejecuto de la siguiente forma:

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.14:3306/bd_requerimiento", "root", "SistemasDaca");
        Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = st.executeQuery(" select sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,r.fecha_envio_rq,a.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo demorado entre fecha de envio y autorizacion',sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,a.fecha_aprobacion,vba.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo demorado entre fecha de autorizacion y almacén',sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,vba.fecha_aprobacion,vbl.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo demorado entre fecha de almacén y logística',sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,vbl.fecha_aprobacion,vbo.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo demorado entre fecha de logística y obra',sec_to_time(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,r.fecha_envio_rq,vbo.fecha_aprobacion)) as 'Tiempo total demorado' from requerimiento r join autorizacion a on r.cod_rq=a.cod_rq join vb_almacen vba on r.cod_rq=vba.cod_rq  join vb_logistica vbl on r.cod_rq=vbl.cod_rq join vb_obra vbo on r.cod_rq=vbo.cod_rq where r.cod_rq ="+txtcod_rq.getText()+ "");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmt = rst.getMetaData();
        int nrocolumnas = rsmt.getColumnCount();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.tablaindicadores.setModel(modelo);
        for (int x = 1; x <= nrocolumnas; x++) {
            modelo.addColumn(rsmt.getColumnLabel(x));

        }

        while (rst.next()) {
            Object[] fila = new Object[nrocolumnas];

            for (int y = 0; y < nrocolumnas; y++) {
                fila[y] = rst.getObject(y + 1);

            }

            modelo.addRow(fila);

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException se) {

        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Adjunto una foto de la prueba en MySQL, asi deberia salir en java :( .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Agradecere cualquier comentario de ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: En qué línea de tu código se está produciendo el error??? Debo suponer que es en la fila[y] = rst.getObject(y + 1);?

Comment: No deberias entonces utilizar la funcion `sec_to_time`, en java 8 puedes usar `java.time.Duration` para trabajar ese lapso de tiempo

Comment: Cordial saludo: Verifica que estés asignando correctamente los parámetros a la función. El error indica que estás asignado un valor de hora igual '58', y esa hora no existe. ¿Estas poniendo los minutos en el campo de la hora?

Comment: Klaimmore, utilizo el sec_to_time en query de mysql

Comment: Raul, el error me da porque cuando corro el query  en la linea: ResultSet rst = st.executeQuery, en ese query estoy haciendo una consulta obteniendo datos de tipo timestamp en mysql y al mismo tiempo haciendo la operacion para obtener la el tiempo de duracion entre un dato y otro y que los bote en horas, minutos y segundos, pero como el total sale mas de 24 horas, en este caso sale 58:13:01 (HORA/MIN/SEG) . cuando pongo mi query en java para imprimirlo en un jtable me aparece ese error.